# Could someone explain Ethgasstation.info headers?

Tags: gas, gas-limit, gas-price

in TXN pool vision of https://ethgasstation.info/txPoolReport.php I am getting confused with the meaning of headers. What does the following headers mean?

```
% of Last 200 Blocks Accepting
% of total transactions mined in last 200 blocks
#Tx at/above in txpool
Pct Mined 5m    
% of Tx Unmined > 5min
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess:

*% of Last 200 Blocks Accepting*: Percentage how many blocks have been accepted (valid blocks) of the last 200 blocks

*% of total transactions mined in last 200 blocks*: Percentage how many transactions have been mined in the last 200 blocks, out of all the seen transactions. So how many of the txs have been added to a valid block

*#Tx at/above in txpool*: Number of transaction waiting to get mined (added to a block)

*Pct Mined 5m*: Percentage(?) of how many transactions are mined within 5 minutes. This guess is probably wrong, though

*% of Tx Unmined > 5min*: Percentage how many transaction require more than 5 minutes to get mined